# what is the better practice when designing MQTT topics for thousands of devices of multiple customers?

Tags: mqtt, mqtt-vernemq

I am developing a MQTT service and I am confused when I design the topics. I think there are two ways to do this:

1. **Topic**   *`data/customer-a`*

   **Payload** *`{"sensor-id":"23aafff2d23659cc97c557909de12f16","type":"demo","value":"hello world"}`*
2. **Topic**   *`data/customer-a/23aafff2d23659cc97c557909de12f16`*

   **Payload** *`{"type":"demo","value":"hello world"}`*

I wonder which is better. I think the first one may result in complexity when I need to subscribe message from a single sensor. Meanwhile, the topic *`data/customer-a`* is always under heavy load because of thousands of messages per second. And the second one has drawbacks too, obviously it makes the mqtt broker maintain a huge topic tree, I don't know whether it would cause significant performance degradation?

Which is better for thousands of devices of multiple customers?

Comment: With option 1 you cannot "subscribe message from a single sensor" at all (you can subscribe to all messages for a customer and then filter the messages received). "the mqtt broker maintain a huge topic tree" not really; when a message arrives its queued for delivery to subscribed connected (and possibly disconnected) clients (see [session state in the spec](https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/os/mqtt-v5.0-os.html#_Toc3901230) for info on what info needs to be held). I'd tend towards 2 but it really depends on your requirements.

Comment: @Brits thx a lot for your reply. Did I misunderstand the vernemq document? Please refer to [mountpoints specification](https://docs.vernemq.com/configuring-vernemq/listeners#mountpoints).

Comment: That looks like a Verne specific add-on (as the document says "Normally an MQTT broker hosts one single topic tree"). I can see that being useful if you run a broker as a managed service (more than one customer may use the `test` topic and should not see each others messages) but it would probably unnecessarily complicate things in your use-case (you control the topics and can use ACL's to limit customer access).

Answer (score 1):

There is no real overhead to a broker "maintaining a massive topic tree" because they don't.

The only thing the broker tracks is the list of subscription patterns that each client has active, it then checks that list every time a message is published.